Sentinel-2 swaths explanation
For the image sent in the attachment, the swath width for Sentinel 2 is 290 km and when I measure the width of this image in the EO browser it is ~290 km and that means there should be one pass of the satellite that was recorded at the same time, why are there swaths on the image of different characteristics (colors) that cause false detections due to this kind of recording, i.e. there are obvious differences in the color of the sea to which then a different threshold should be applied in order to highlight the same object.
Can you explain to me satellite remote sensing process during a single pass, should there be swaths of different colors and why?


Possible duplicate? Seam in band 1 of sentinel 2 data

maybe ad a scale-bar to your image to clearify the issue better.

If your image is the exact width of a swath, you should expect there to always be two images in a tile, and since the swaths are diagonal, sometimes three.

is there any paper that explain that?

Take some construction paper, mark it with diagonal strips, then cut out a rectangle with the same width  at the strip size, drop it randomly, and rotate it to align with the sheet -- How many strips does it touch? Has to be two, might be three. What journal would accept that paper?

It's called the parallax effect - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/482183/2856

Thank you!
And do you know how can I solve false detection based on parallax effect because of different normalized index values?

@user243807 - the transition between the stripes is not clean, so detecting and dealing with the transition is not straight forward, unfortunately.
